# IE9 Javascript - Different behaviour when multiple tabs are open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a very odd issue in IE9...

Basically, I have a page that implements a custom right-click menu for a rich editor, but the menu is disappearing as soon as it displays.

However, and here's the odd bit; if I open a second tab in my IE window (doesn't matter where the tab goes, about:blank, Google, whatever), the menu works!

Can anybody offer a possible explanation? Surely, the mere presence of a second tab shouldn't affect my code!? It doesn't happen when I open a new IE window and the amount of tabs doesn't have any effect. i.e. 1 tab = menu closes immediately, 2+ tabs = menu works.

I've also not been able to reproduce the issue in prior versions of IE. I don't have an IE10 environment handy at the moment...

Comment: Please share a jsfiddle link so one can get batter idea.

Comment: I'm really looking for an explanation of why/how the presence of a second tab can affect the code, rather than a fix for this specific issue. Also, it's commercially-developed code that's part of a larger system and would take quite a bit of anonymising, etc...

Comment: Still, without the specific code we won't be able to help too much. What menu does the right click open? Is it a custom menu? where did it come from?